# Remove "Part" from the \part{stuff} headings

Tags: parts, report, minitoc

This is the main code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\begin{document}
\doparttoc

\tableofcontents

\part{MEMORIA}
\parttoc

\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section1.1}
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2.1}

\end{document}
```

Command `\part` returns:

```
  Part I

 MEMORIA
```

How could be 'Part' supressed, without using titlesec package? I'd like to get:

```
 I. MEMORIA
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\part` calls `\@part`, which calls `\sv@part`, which defines the appearance of the title page (among other things).

You can change the relevant code of `\sv@part` with the `xpatch` package, using `\xpatchcmd{command to modify}{code to replace}{replacement code}{do if success}{do if fail}`. Because the command `\sv@part` contains an `@` character you need to put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around the patch.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\sv@part}{\huge \bfseries \partname \nobreakspace \thepart \par \vskip 20\p@ \fi \Huge \bfseries #2}{\fi \Huge \bfseries \thepart. #2}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\doparttoc

\tableofcontents

\part{MEMORIA}
\parttoc

\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section1.1}
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2.1}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This code helped me a lot. I also was able to change title FontSize modifying it, which i needed it too.